# Add another back button to a Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have a navigation controller so when I click on a button on my main view, it opens another view with the "Back" navigation item.

What I'm trying to do is to add another item on my second view on the right, so this view should have a "Back" item, already working, and a new "Edit" item which does the same thing as Back button but I can get the prepareForSegue function to run some code in complement.

How can I achieve to do that ?

Here is what I tried :

[image]

I'm using two navigation controllers because I couldn't add an "Edit" item if my second view wasn't embed in a navigation controller.
So this is working, I have my two "Back" and "Edit" items, but I don't know how to manage to get the same behavior as the "Back" item on my "Edit" item, I tried segues but it doesn't work as expected.
Note that the button I talked about on my first view isn't shown in the editor nor its segue, I did it programmatically.

Comment: prepareForSegue is for pushing ViewController not for PopViewController, What you are asking here is how to send data back to previous ViewController if I am getting you right ?-

Comment: Could you describe what's the issue what are you trying to solve in general instead of asking about implementing a specific behavior which might be not elegant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple call `popViewController(animated:)` when the `edit button` is tapped.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let editItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Edit", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(editButtonTapped(_:)))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editItem

    }

    @objc func editButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem)
    {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

**Storyboard:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly, I tried something too complex when the solution was simple. Now the last thing I don't understand is how could I add this edit button via the editor ? A simple drag on the second view does nothing, that's why I used a second navigation controller where I could put this edit button.